# Join tuples inside list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have:

```
mylist = [(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]), (['c', 'd'], [3])]
```

I need one list with the letters and one with the numbers, like this:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3])
```

I have made some efforts, but I could just get one list with the letters, not both:

```
answer = [item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist[0]]
#returns ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: `answer = [[item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist[i]] for i in range(2)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`answer = [[item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist[i]] for i in range(2)]`

Just need to iterate through your sublist :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple alternative using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
[list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in zip(*mylist)]
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: `chain` is nice... alternatively you could avoid it and just use a nested list-comp, eg: `[[a for b in el for a in b] for el in zip(*mylist)]`

Comment: Yes there's always the list-comp alternative to flatten lists @JonClements, `chain` is nice though for conciseness and performance

Comment: Indeed... in terms of efficiency though, you probably want to go for `chain.from_iterable(i)` instead of `chain(*i)` as it exists exactly for that case (and imho is even more explicit than unpacking)

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) works as well:

```
tuple(map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1],  zip(mylist[0], mylist[1])))
```

**Code**:

```
mylist = [(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]), (['c', 'd'], [3])]

print(tuple(map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1],  zip(mylist[0], mylist[1]))))
# (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3])
```